# Linux shell command parameter

Tags: linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am executing a shell command line in python but would like to change some data of parameter line. For example:

```
'sudo tools/hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1E 02 01 1A 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 63 6F 3F 8F 64 91 4B EE 95 F7 D8 CC 64 A8 63 B5 00 00 00 00 C8'
```

Will broadcast a BLE signal with Major 00 and Minor 00

```
'sudo tools/hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1E 02 01 1A 1A FF 4C 00 02 15 63 6F 3F 8F 64 91 4B EE 95 F7 D8 CC 64 A8 63 B5' + '00 00' + '00 00' + 'C8'
```

Will not run properly, later will change '00 00' and '00 00' to Major and Minor variables.

How can I run succesfully the second command? Thanks!

Comment: What language are you calling this from?  Your first line will not work if you paste it directly into a bash shell -- the quotes around the line make it be seen as a single entity in bash, and will return a command not found error.  Therefore, you're in some other language, how is this shell command being executed?  I think it's more about that language you're writing this in, than the actual `sudo tools/hcitool` command itself.

Comment: Get an easier command to work first `sudo ls /path/to/small/dir` Or similar, Then add something to that command, when you have that working then work on your hcitool string. Good luck.